# How are portlets rendered / ordered / layed out in Plone?

Tags: plone

I'm trying to change the global ordering of the portlets in my Plone site. I've searched the Plone source code but I can't find the code that actually iterates through and renders the portlets, for example the 'plone.rightcolumn' and 'plone.leftcolumn' content providers. Where is that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/old/portlets/rendered.html for technical details (imho this is still up-to-date)

The [PortletRetriever](https://github.com/plone/plone.portlets/blob/master/plone/portlets/retriever.py) (plone.portlets) collects and orders all portlet assignments.

The [PortletManagerRenderer](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.portlets/blob/master/plone/app/portlets/manager.py) uses the informations of the retriever to render the column

Also have a look at the code of [Solgema.PortletsManager](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Solgema.PortletsManager) they improved the PortletRetriever, this is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: See also Martin Aspeli's [Introduction to Plone portlets](http://www.martinaspeli.net/articles/an-introduction-to-plone-portlets) from 2008.

Comment: +1, all the infos one needs :) And I have to check out Solgema.PortletsManager, too. Thanks!